# Import rust module intwo two different modules

Tags: rust

I have a util module providing constants and some simple utilties for these constants to two different modules in my tree:

```
 - main.rs
 - util.rs
 - game.rs
```

I'd like both `main.rs` and `game.rs` to include code from the `util.rs` module, meaning I'd want both of them including it with

```
mod util;
use util::{SIZE, TRANSFORM};
```

However the `game.rs` module does not allow its import, stating:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `util`
  --> src/game.rs:17:1
   |
17 | mod util;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `util`, create file "src/game/util.rs"
```

I do not want to make the util module a submodule of the game module, since its constants will be used across many different modules. How do I go about to achieve a flat file hierarchy for importing a module into two different modules?

Comment: Is this just a typo? `util` vs `utils`?

Comment: typo in the question, the code was `utils`.

Comment: Top level modules should be declared in `main.rs`. If you want to use them elsewhere, just `use` them. Don't make another module with `mod util`;.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd mark that as the answer if I could.